# How to print ArrayList within a taglib

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, servlet-3.0

I am trying to print a list of contacts by passing it to a taglib,

here is my code:

Controller.java:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException{

        try {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("test", getAll());
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/views/index.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }

private List<Contact> getAll() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    con = DbController.connect();
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contact");
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    while(rs.next())

        contacts.add(new Contact(rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("phone")));

    contacts.add(new Contact("name", "phone"));

    return contacts;
}
```

contact.tld:

```
<tag>
        <name>contact</name>
        <tag-class>contactsBook.Models.ContactTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>contact</name>
            <!--means Runtime Expression Value. It means the attribute can support 
                scriptlet values. -->
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
            <type>myModels.Contact</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/contact.tld" prefix="contactTag"%>
<c:forEach items="${test}" var="contact">
    <contactTag:contact contact="${contact}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

the responded page didn't print the code inside the `<c:forEach>`, so what is the problem in my code?

Comment: does `getAll()` return a good list of contacts, or `null` ?

Comment: Having `if (rs.next` and `while (rs.next` looks dodgy - what happens if only one contact?

Comment: sure, ok, but still, if the SQL query doesn't return anything, you won't print anything. Ignore the database call for now, hard code a list of 3 Contacts and pass it in to the jsp, does it print correctly? yes - your database code is wrong, no - your tag/jsp is wrong. either way its information

Comment: do you get output if you simple do `<c:forEach items="${test}" var="contact"> ${contact} </c:forEach>`

Comment: Suddenly its working now without changing a single piece of code !

Comment: did you turn on the database computer? :)

Comment: @jb. sure it was turned on.